# Why is there hyphen(-) after user-agent in http access logs

Tags: apache, nginx, logging, http-headers

Today i was parsing http access log ,while doing parsing i notice that there is **-** in the last(after user-agent)
I checked on Internet but there didn't find anything.

I am sharing the logs

```
54.36.149.41 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:14 +0330] "GET /filter/27|13%20%D9%85%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B3%D9%84,27|%DA%A9%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D8%B2%205%20%D9%85%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B3%D9%84,p53 HTTP/1.1" 200 30577 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/6.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)" "-"
```

Is this last   **-** hyphen has some meaning or it just done by mistake. I have download this web server log from kaggle.

I know basic http log format can be

```
%h – Remote host (client IP address)
%l – User identity, or dash, if none (often not used)
%u – Username, via HTTP authentication, or dash if not used
%t – Timestamp of when Apache received the HTTP request
”%r – The actual request itself from the client
%>s – The status code Apache returns in response to the request
%b – The size of the request in bytes.
”%{Referer}i” – Referrer header, or dash if not used  (In other words, did they click a URL on another site to come to your site)
”%{User-agent}i – User agent (contains information about the requester’s browser/OS/etc)
```

But in this case what i would call this hyphen which i seeing in last line

Comment: *... http log format can be*.  What is the actual configuration in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: I have downloaded this data it is a sample data set

Comment: Please add in your question (not here in the comments) the actual `LogFormat` line in your configuration.  We need to know what configuration you use to figure out what that `"-"` is in your log sample

Comment: As i said before i have downloaded this sample log i am not aware of the log format

Comment: without the configuration that matches the output, its impossible to know.